# cant move copy or delete files on other disk on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, nautilus, ssd

[image]

Hello. As you can see here, there are three items: the"计算机"(for Ubuntu 18.04) and "new_add"(for store data) are on the same physical SSD (1T); the "sys" (for win 10) is on another physical SSD(1T).

Yesterday, I can move, copy, and delete files on "sys" and "new_add" but today, I can't do these actions.

Even if I use the `sudo nautilus` command to open files, in this situation, I  still can't copy, move, or delete files.

If anyone can please help, I would appreciate it. Thanks very much!

Comment: Is Windows in a hibernated or fastboot state when you cannot copy, move, or delete files?

Comment: Also, this is unrelated to your current issue but when you run a GUI application like nautilus, you should use `sudo -i` instead of `sudo` to prevent problems.

Comment: hi,when I  cant copy,move,delete files, i am in the ubuntu 18.04,not in win 10

Comment: and   sudo -i nautilus   is not work for me,, i stiil cant move ,copy ,delete   on"new_add"   and "sys"

Comment: hi,many thanks to you,my problem  solved!!!!!!!

Comment: Awesome. You can mark this as the accepted solution by clicking the check-mark icon to the left of the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu cannot change files on a disk or partition that is in an "unstable" or hibernated state. If Windows is not completely shut down properly, Ubuntu will access these partitions as read-only

To fix this problem, boot up Windows, search for the "fastboot" Windows option, and disable fastboot.

Next, make sure to completely power off Windows and do not hibernate.

Then, when you turn your computer back on and boot up Ubuntu, you should be able to move, copy, and delete files.